# calendar not showing correct members events

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, mysqli

i have a website with multiple members, i want each if them to have their own calendar.
i found a tutorial to build and events calendar witch works fine but i am having trouble trying to get the events to show on the correct calendar, either everyone can see all events in the database or no one can see any.

my code is as follows

calendar_start.php

```
<?php 

$showmonth = $_POST['showmonth'];
$showyear = $_POST['showyear'];
$showmonth = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i', '', $showmonth);
$showyear = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i', '', $showyear);


$day_count = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $showmonth, $showyear);
$pre_days = date('w', mktime(0,0,0, $showmonth, 1, $showyear));
$post_days = (6 - (date('w', mktime(0,0,0, $showmonth, $day_count, $showyear))));

echo '<div id="calender_wrap">';

echo '<div class="title_bar">';
echo '<div class="previouse_month"><input name="myBtn" type="submit" value="Previouse Month" onclick="javascript:last_month();"></div';
echo '<div class="show_month">' . $showmonth . '/' . $showyear . '</div>';
echo '<div class="next_month"><input name="myBtn" type="submit" value="Next Month" onclick="javascript:next_month();"></div>';
echo '</div>';

echo '<div class="week_days">';
echo '<div class="days_of_week">Sunday</div>';
echo '<div class="days_of_week">Monday</div>';
echo '<div class="days_of_week">Tuesday</div>';
echo '<div class="days_of_week">Wednesday</div>';
echo '<div class="days_of_week">Thursday</div>';
echo '<div class="days_of_week">Friday</div>';
echo '<div class="days_of_week">saturday</div>';
echo '<div class="clear"></div>';
echo '</div>';

/* Previouse Month filler Days */
if ($pre_days != 0) {
    for($i = 1; $i<=$pre_days; $i++) {
        echo '<div class="non_cal_day"></div>';
    }
}

/*Current Month filler Days */
include("scripts/connect_to_mysql.php");
for($i = 1; $i<= $day_count; $i++) {
    // get event logic

    $date = $i . '/' . $showmonth . '/' . $showyear;
    $query = "SELECT * FROM occurrences WHERE cid ='$squadid' AND start_date ='$date' ";
    $cal = mysqli_query($db_conx, $query);
    $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($cal);
        if($num_rows > 0) {
            $event= '<a href="view_events.php"><h3 class="event_here">Events Here</h3></a>';
            }
        //end get event logic

    echo '<div class="cal_day">';
    echo '<div class="day_heading">' . $i . ' <a href="add_event.php"><div class="add_event"></div></a></div><br/>';
    if($num_rows != 0) { echo $event;}
    echo '</div>';
}

/* Next month filler days */
if ($post_days != 0) {
    for($i = 1; $i<=$post_days; $i++) {
        echo '<div class="non_cal_day"></div>';
    }
}

echo '</div>';

?>
```

show_calendar.php

```
<?php 
// Start_session, check if user is logged in or not, and connect to the database all in one included file
include_once("scripts/checkuserlog.php");
// Include the class files for auto making links out of full URLs and for Time Ago date formatting
include_once("wi_class_files/autoMakeLinks.php");
include_once ("wi_class_files/agoTimeFormat.php");
// Create the two new objects before we can use them below in this script
$activeLinkObject = new autoActiveLink;
$myObject = new convertToAgo;

// ------- ESTABLISH THE PAGE ID ACCORDING TO CONDITIONS ---------
$squadid = "";
if (isset($_GET['pid'])){ $squadid = $_GET['pid'];};
// ------- END ESTABLISH THE PAGE ID ACCORDING TO CONDITIONS ---------

//-------- GET EVENTS FROM TABLE-------------------------------------

?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Calender</title>
<link href="style/calCss.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
<link href="style/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link rel="icon" href="logoicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="logoicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function initialCalendar() {
    var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "calender_start.php";
    var currentTime = new Date();
    var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1;
    var year = currentTime.getFullYear();
    showmonth = month;
    showyear = year;
    var vars = "showmonth="+showmonth+"&showyear="+showyear;
    hr.open("POST", url, true);
    hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
            var return_data = hr.responseText;
            document.getElementById("showCalendar") .innerHTML = return_data;
        }
    }
    hr.send(vars);
    document.getElementById("showCalendar") .innerHTML = "processing...";
}
</script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function next_month() {
    var nextmonth = showmonth + 1;
    if(nextmonth > 12) {
        nextmonth = 1;
        showyear = showyear + 1;
    }
    showmonth = nextmonth;
    var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "calender_start.php";
    var vars = "showmonth="+showmonth+"&showyear="+showyear;
    hr.open("POST", url, true);
    hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
            var return_data = hr.responseText;
            document.getElementById("showCalendar").innerHTML = return_data;
        }
    }
    hr.send(vars);
    document.getElementById("showCalendar").innerHTML = "processing...";
}
</script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
function last_month() {
    var lastmonth = showmonth - 1;
    if(lastmonth < 1) {
        lastmonth = 12;
        showyear = showyear - 1;
    }
    showmonth = lastmonth;
    var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "calender_start.php";
    var vars = "showmonth="+showmonth+"&showyear="+showyear;
    hr.open("POST", url, true);
    hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
            var return_data = hr.responseText;
            document.getElementById("showCalendar").innerHTML = return_data;
        }
    }
    hr.send(vars);
    document.getElementById("showCalendar").innerHTML = "processing...";
}
</script>
</head>

<body onload="initialCalendar();">
<?php include_once "header_template.php"; ?>
<table class="mainBodyTable" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="740" valign="top"><div><?php include_once "leaderBoardAd.php"; ?></div><br />
      <table width="90%" align="center" cellpadding="6">
        <tr>
          <td>
          <div id="showCalendar"></div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table></td>
    <td width="160" valign="top"><?php include_once "right_AD_template.php"; ?></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<?php include_once "footer_template.php"; ?>

</body>
</html>
```

currently if i remove the `cid ='$squadid'` from the `$query` in calendar_start.php you can see all events in the database but every member on the site can also see them.

in my table the `cid` should stand for calendar id ie. the members own calendar but i cannot work out where i am going wrong.

i hope i have explained this well enough but if you need more just let me know.

many thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your calendar_start.php (that is the file trigered by your ajax requests) the var $squadid is empty. You need to send $squadid from show_calendar.php to calendar_start.php throw your ajax requests.

Here is an example:

```
  //Ajax request example from show_calendar.php
    var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "calender_start.php";
    var currentTime = new Date();
    var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1;
    var year = currentTime.getFullYear();
    showmonth = month;
    showyear = year;
    var vars = "showmonth="+showmonth+"&showyear="+showyear+"&squadid=<?= $squadid; ?>";
    hr.open("POST", url, true);
    hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
            var return_data = hr.responseText;
            document.getElementById("showCalendar") .innerHTML = return_data;
        }
    }
    hr.send(vars);
    document.getElementById("showCalendar") .innerHTML = "processing...";


    //Get the var in calendar_start.php add this line
    $squadid = $_POST['squadid'];
```

Hope this help you m8.
Cheers!

Comment: Hi Georgian, i have tried your suggestion but still cannot get it to work unfortunately. am i correct in putting $squadid = $_POST['squadid']; in to the calendar_start.php?

Comment: first af all, send it from ajax , then it;s correct what you've done

Comment: when you mean send it through ajax do you mean this line: var vars = "showmonth="+showmonth+"&showyear="+showyear+"&squadid=<?= $squadid; ?>"; if so i have added this but still cant see the events. Am i missing something else? its usually something really obviouse when i get in these little ruts haha. thanks for your help so far though